# How to pass condition in laravel 5 relation model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-models

I am trying to get the data from group model but i am relate the student table `new_group_id` to group table id if it not null else connect the `group_id` to group table id.

```
public function grade(Builder $query)
{
    return $query
        ->when($this->new_group_id != 0, function ($q) {
            return $q->with('new_group_id');
        })
        ->when($this->new_group_id === 0, function ($q) {
            return $q->with('group_id');
        });
}
```

But given the error is

> Argument 1 passed to App\Students::grade() must be an instance of
> App\Builder

please help me to solve these error

Comment: The error is from the call of the method `grade()` not the method itself.

Comment: You have two relations named `newGroupId()` and `groupId()` in your model ?

Comment: newgroupid and groupid is database column

Comment: doing like these return $this->hasone('App\Groups','id','group_id'); else return $this->hasone('App\Groups','id','new_group_id');

Comment: Read these two documentation on relation and eager loading https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading -- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: the relation should be `belongsTo()` not `hasOne()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're using a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) which Laravel will resolve and inject an instance of `Builder` into your function via the [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container).

For this to happen though you need to follow the Laravel convention of prefixing your local scope with the word `scope`:

```
public function scopeGrade($query)
{
    return $query
      ->when($this->new_group_id != 0,function($q){
          return $q->with('new_group_id');
      })
      ->when($this->new_group_id === 0,function($q){
          return $q->with('group_id');
      });
}
```

Comment: given error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints().

Comment: how to match this with group table id??

Comment: @MaitrikThakkar You'll want to use a `where` clause rather than a `with`.